# using flutter to build a browser application

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-ios

I want to start working on a new browser application for ios devices. Can I use flutter and the webview_flutter plugin to build a custom browser like google chrome or monzila for IOS Devices

Comment: why are flutter answers so slow